Interesting integration : $\int^1_0\left({\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}-p}\right)\frac{dx}{\ln(x)}$
I need help evaluating this integral: $$I=\int^1_0\left({\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}-p}\right)\frac{dx}{\ln(x)}$$
where $p\ge1$
We have
$$\frac{x-1}{\ln(x)}=\int^1_0x^t \, dt$$
Therefore:
$$I=\int^1_0\int^1_0\left({\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}-p}\right)\frac{x^t}{x-1} \, dx \, dt$$
Source: Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, Eighth Edition,  page 549

Is $p$ an integer, or is that not guaranteed?

p is a positive real number greater than or equal to 1

Ok, if $p$ was an integer, it would be very easy to get $I = \ln(p!)$. I suspect $I = \ln(\Gamma(p+1))$ for non-integer $p$.

I tried some numerical cases.  They agreed with $\ln(\Gamma(p+1))$.

We can also find the solution for any $p>-1$
Let's consider a bit more general case
$$I(\alpha, p)=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}-p\right)\frac{x^\alpha}{\ln x}dx$$
$$I(\alpha, p)'_\alpha=\int^1_0\left(\frac{x^\alpha-x^{p+\alpha}}{1-x}-px^\alpha\right)dx=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1-x^{p+\alpha}}{1-x}-\frac{1-x^\alpha}{1-x}-px^\alpha\right)dx$$
Using the presentation of digamma-function $\,\displaystyle \psi(1+s)=-\gamma+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^s}{1-t}dt$
$$I(\alpha, p)'_\alpha=\psi(1+p+\alpha)-\psi(1+\alpha)-\frac p{1+\alpha}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,I(\alpha, p)=\ln\Gamma(1+p+\alpha)-\ln\Gamma(1+\alpha)-p\ln(1+\alpha)+C$$
where the constant $C$ can be found from the condition $\displaystyle \lim_{\alpha\to\infty}I(\alpha,p)=0\,$:
$$\ln\Gamma(1+p+\alpha)-\ln\Gamma(1+\alpha)=\ln\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1+p+\alpha)}{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1+\alpha)}$$
$$\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(1+p+\alpha)}=B(1+\alpha;p)=\int_0^1x^{p-1}(1-x)^\alpha dx$$
$$=\int_0^1x^{p-1}e^{\alpha\ln(1-x)} dx\to\frac{\Gamma(p)}{\alpha^p}\left(1+O\Big(\frac1\alpha\Big)\right)\,\,\text{at}\,\,\alpha\to\infty$$
$$I(\alpha, p)\to\ln\frac{\Gamma(p)\alpha^p}{\Gamma(p)}-p\ln(1+\alpha)+C\to0\,\,\text{at}\,\,\alpha\to \infty\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,C=0$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(\alpha,p)=\int^1_0\left(\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}-p\right)\frac{x^\alpha}{\ln x}dx=\ln\frac{\Gamma(1+p+\alpha)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}-p\ln(1+\alpha)\,\,}$$
and the desired integral
$$I_0=I(\alpha=0,p)=\ln\Gamma(1+p)$$

Nice Solution +1)

Nice generalization.

Thank you  very much!

Partial answer for the case where $p \ge 1$ is an integer:
For $0 < x < 1$, we have $$\dfrac{1-x^p}{1-x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}x^k$$ and thus, $$I(p) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{1-x^p}{1-x}-p\right)\dfrac{dx}{\ln x} = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}\dfrac{x^k-1}{\ln x}\right)\,dx = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^k-1}{\ln x}\,dx.$$
For each $k = 0, \ldots p-1$, we can use the standard Feynman Integration trick to get $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^k-1}{\ln x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{k}x^y\,dy\,dx = \int_{0}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}x^y\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{k}\dfrac{1}{y+1}\,dy = \ln(k+1).$$
Therefore, $$I(p) = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^k-1}{\ln x}\,dx = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}\ln(k+1) = \ln(1 \cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdots p) = \ln(p!).$$
In case it is useful for someone to solve the general case:
Note that for any $p \ge 1$, we have $$I(p)-I(p-1) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{x^{p-1}-x^p}{1-x}-1\right)\dfrac{dx}{\ln x} = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{p-1}-1}{\ln x}\,dx = \ln(p)$$ using the same Feynman Integration trick. Hence, I think it is reasonable to conjecture that $I(p) = \ln(\Gamma(p+1))$ for $p \ge 1$. Of course, it isn't a proof.

You could have used $$\int\dfrac{x^k-1}{\ln x},dx =\int \frac{e^t \left(e^{k t}-1\right)}{t} ,dt=\text{Ei}((k+1) t)-\text{Ei}(t)$$

Alternatively, we can show that  $$I = -\lim_{s \to 0} \Gamma(s) \left(\zeta(s,1)-\zeta(s,p+1)-p \right) = \ln \Gamma(p+1), \quad p >-1,$$
where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function.

Making the substitution $t = - \ln(x)$, we have $$I= -\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-e^{-pt}}{1-e^{-t}}-p \right) \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, \mathrm dt.$$
Let $I(p,s)$ be the Mellin transform $$ I(p,s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-e^{-pt}}{1-e^{-t}}-p \right) t^{s-1} e^{-t} \, \mathrm dt, $$ which, for fixed $p$, defines an analytic function in the region $\Re(s) >-1$. (See here.)
So that we can break up $I(p,s)$ into three separate integrals, let's first assume that $\Re(s) >1$.
Then $$ \begin{align} I(p,s) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1} e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}} \, \mathrm dt - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1} e^{-(p+1)t}}{1-e^{-t}} \, \mathrm dt - p \int_{0}^{\infty}  t^{s-1} e^{-t} \, \mathrm dt \\ &\overset{\diamondsuit}{=} \Gamma(s)\zeta(s,1)- \Gamma(s)\zeta(s,p+1)-p \Gamma(s). \end{align}$$

$\diamondsuit$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Integral_representation

We'll now show that $$\Gamma(s) \left( \zeta(s,1)- \zeta(s,p+1)-p \right)  $$ has removable singularities $s=1$ and $s=0$:
$$ \begin{align}  &\lim_{s \to 1} \Gamma(s) \left(\zeta(s,1)-\zeta(s,p+1)-p \right) \\ &\overset{\spadesuit}{=} 1 \times\lim_{s \to 1} \left(\frac{1}{s-1}- \psi(1)+O(s-1) - \frac{1}{s-1}+ \psi(p+1)+O(s-1) -p\right) \\ &= - \psi(1) + \psi(p+1)-p \end{align}$$
and
$$ \begin{align} &\lim_{s \to 0} \Gamma(s) \left(\zeta(s,1)-\zeta(s,p+1)-p \right) \\ &\overset{\clubsuit}{=} \small \lim_{s \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{s} + O(1) \right) \left(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\ln(2 \pi)}{2}s +O(s^{2}) -\frac{1}{2}+(p+1)- \left( \ln \Gamma(p+1) - \frac{\ln(2 \pi)}{2} \right)s +O(s^{2})-p\right) \\ &= \lim_{s \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{s} + O(1) \right) \left(- s \ln \Gamma(p+1)+O(s^{2}) \right) \\ &= \lim_{s \to 0} \left(- \ln \Gamma(p+1)+O(s)  \right) \\ &= - \ln \Gamma(p+1) \end{align}$$

$\spadesuit$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Laurent_series
$\clubsuit$ https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E13 , https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E18

If we assign $\Gamma(s) \left( \zeta(s,1)- \zeta(s,p+1)-p \right) $ its limit values at $s=1$ and $s=0$, then $$I(p,s) =  \Gamma(s) \left( \zeta(s,1)- \zeta(s,p+1)-p \right)$$ holds for $\Re(s) >-1$ by the identity theorem.
Therefore, we have $$I = - I(p,0) = -\lim_{s \to 0} \Gamma(s) \left(\zeta(s,1)-\zeta(s,p+1)-p \right) =  \ln \Gamma(p+1). $$

Very nice solution +1)

$$I(p)=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}-p\right)\frac{1}{ln(x)}\,dx$$
$$I^{'}(p)=-\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^p\ln(x)}{1-x}+1\right)\frac{1}{ln(x)}\,dx$$
Set $p=0$,
$$I^{'}(p)|_{p=0}=-\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right)\,dx$$
Set $\ln(x) = -t\implies \,dx=-e^{-t}\,dt$,
$$I^{'}(p)|_{p=0}=-\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{1}{e^t-1}\right)\,dt$$
Comparing with the below well known result,
$$\boxed{{\displaystyle \psi (z)=\int _{0}^{\infty }\left({\frac {e^{-t}}{t}}-{\frac {e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}}\right)\,dt}}$$
By setting $z=1$ and using $\psi^{(0)}(1)=-\gamma$,
$$I^{'}(p)|_{p=0}=-\gamma$$
$$I^{''}(p)=-\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^p}{1-x}{\ln(x)}\right)\,dx$$
the above integral can be evaluated from this
$$I^{''}(p)=\psi^{(1)}(1+p)$$
$$I^{'}(p)=\psi^{(0)}(1+p)+K$$
Using the result,
$$\boxed{\int \psi^{(0)}(1+x)\,dx=\ln(\Gamma(x+1))}$$
$$p=0 \implies K=0$$
$$I(p)=\ln(\Gamma(1+p))+C$$
$$p=1 \implies C=0$$
$$\boxed{I(p)=\ln(\Gamma(1+p))}$$
